# Sum of fractions with restricted domain and range

Tags: inequality

Find all positive integers $m$ and $n$ so that for any $x$ and $y$ in the interval $[m, n]$, the value of $5/x + 7/y$ will also be in $ [m, n]$.

I evaluated the inequalities into

$(ym-5)(xm-7) < 35$

$(yn-5)(xn-7) > 35$

but can't really think of what to do next.

Comment: Are $x,y$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: yes they are000

Comment: You need $12n\le n$, which is a bit difficult for non-zero numbers. Where did you get this question?

Comment: http://pmo.ph/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/16th-PMO-Area.pdf

Comment: Its a bit early into the test (number 6), O

Comment: I just realized that the qyestion was wrong ;O, someone edited out the fraction part when i was away, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**  You need $m\le 12/n$ and $n\ge 12/m$ so $mn=12$, find the possibilities for positive integers $m<n$…